# Xamarin first images on ListView not being shown unless user scrolls further down

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Custom Adapter

```
class MoviesAdapter : BaseAdapter<Movies>
    {
        private List<Movies> movie_list;
        private Context context;

        public MoviesAdapter(Context context, List<Movies> movie_list)
        {
            this.movie_list = movie_list;
            this.context = context;

        }

        public override Movies this[int position]
        {
            get{ return movie_list[position]; }
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get{ return movie_list.Count; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;  
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            ViewHolder holder;
            var row = convertView;

            if(row != null)
            {
                holder = row.Tag as ViewHolder;
            }

            else 
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(this.context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.show_times, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder();

                holder.title = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.movie_title);
                holder.rating = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.movie_rating);
                holder.summary = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.movie_description);
                holder.poster = row.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.poster);
                row.Tag = holder;

            }

            holder.title.Text = movie_list[position].title;
            holder.rating.Text = movie_list[position].rating;
            holder.summary.Text = movie_list[position].summary;

            if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(movie_list[position].poster))
            {
                holder.poster.SetImageBitmap(movie_list[position].image);
            }
            else
            {
                holder.poster.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
            }


            return row;
        }
```

My Activity:

```
public class ShowTimes : Activity

    {
        private List<Movies> movie_list = new List<Movies>();

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Activity2);
            string theater_name = Intent.GetStringExtra("theater_name");

            TextView theater = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.theater_name);
            ListView movies_view = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.movies);
            theater.Text = theater_name;
            var movies = this.get_movies(theater_name);
            foreach(var movie in movies)
            {
                Movies movie_object = movie.ToObject<Movies>();
                if(movie_object.poster != null)
                {
                    download_image(movie_object);
                }
                movie_list.Add(movie_object);

            }
            MoviesAdapter movie_adpater = new MoviesAdapter(this, movie_list);
            movies_view.Adapter = movie_adpater;
        }



        private JArray get_movies(string theater_name)
        {
            var encode_arg = WebUtility.UrlEncode($"{theater_name}");
            string url = $"http://some_address/api/get_showtimes?theater=" + encode_arg;
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

            request.Method = "GET";

            var api_response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            string output;

            using (StreamReader response_stream = new StreamReader(api_response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                output = response_stream.ReadToEnd();
            }

            JObject movies = JObject.Parse(output);
            return (JArray)movies["response"];
        }



        public async void download_image(Movies movie_object)
        {
            using (var webclient = new WebClient())
            {
                var image_bytes = await webclient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(movie_object.poster);
                var bit_map = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(image_bytes, 0, image_bytes.Length);
                movie_object.image = bit_map;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

this is what it looks like

[image]

but on scrolling down the images all appear and when scrolling up the previous images in the picture above would show.

whats going on and how do we fix it?

Im confused because. The descriptions are there and everything it's just the images that are acting funny.

Comment: I would load the images in the MoviesAdapter.GetView, the way you are doing it now doesn't take any advantage of row virtualization and you are loading images you may never use.

Comment: @BillReiss i've tried doing that but since these images aren't stored in memory. they change a lot when you scroll. when set on the MoviesAdapter.GetView. Im guessing I need a caching solution for this

Comment: You can look at Akavache for easy image caching http://trsneed.com/just-use-akavache-again/